# Can this sum be simplified to closed form?

Tags: number-theory, summation

$$\sum_{a=1}^{L} L\left\lfloor\frac{(L-a)b}{L}\right\rfloor^2$$

$L,b$ are known, positive integers. Can this be reduced to a closed form? Mathematica isn't helping me out much here.

Comment: Would a bound be good enough?

Comment: I'm not sure how to prove it but it seems that the following might be true: set $S(L,b) = \sum_{a=0}^{L-1} \lfloor ab/L\rfloor^2$, and write $L = nb+t$ then $S(L,t) = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 + S(t,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{a=1}^{L}L\left\lfloor\frac{(L-a)b}{L}\right\rfloor^2=L\sum_{a=0}^{L-1}\left\lfloor\frac{ab}{L}\right\rfloor^2\le \frac{b^2}L \sum_{a=0}^{L-1}a^2=\frac{b^2(L-1)(2L-1)}{6}$$
and
$$> L\sum_{a=0}^{L-1}\left(\frac{ab}{L}-1\right)^2=L\sum_{1=0}^{L-1}\left(\frac{b^2a^2}{L^2}-\frac{2ab}{L}+1\right)=\frac{b^2(L-1)(2L-1)}{6}-bL(L-1)+L^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider this sum, as you mentioned:

$$
\sum_{a=1}^L L\left\lfloor\frac{(L-a)b}{L}\right\rfloor^2 = \sum_{a=1}^L L(\frac{(L-a)b}{L})^2 = L\sum_{a=1}^L (\frac{(L-a)^2b^2}{L^2}) = \frac{1}{L}\sum_{a=1}^L ((L-a)^2b^2) =
\frac{1}{L}\sum_{a=1}^L ((L-a)^2b^2) = \frac{b^2}{L}\sum_{a=1}^L (L-a)^2
$$

Maybe the remaining expression can be simplified further...

EDIT(!!!):

I thought those are brackets, but apparently it's the floor function, therefore, the sum cannot be simplified more than you wrote it...

Comment: FYI, $\lfloor\circ\rfloor$ denotes the [floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions); it cannot simply be erased from the expression like this.

Comment: Oh I thought those are simply brackets. Thanks @anon. my answer is incorrect then, I'll edit